# Sample 'hello' application from boxfuse does not work

Tags: cloudcaptain

Created the account, tried to run the sample 'hello' app.

$ boxfuse run hello-1.0.war

Boxfuse client v.1.8.6.659
Copyright 2015 Boxfuse GmbH. All rights reserved.

Account: xxx (xxx)

Downloading glibc 2.21 ...
Downloading busybox 1.22.1.01 ...
Downloading openjdk 8.60.22 ...
Downloading libgcc 4.9.2 ...
Downloading libpng 1.2.52 ...
Downloading zlib 1.2.8 ...
Downloading freetype 2.6 ...
Downloading ttf-bitstream-vera 1.10 ...
Downloading cacerts 2014.11.17 ...
Downloading tomcat 8.0.23 ...
Downloading linux 3.15.9 ...
Fusing Image for hello-1.0.war ...
ERROR: Both the http and the https ports are disabled. You must specify at least one for Tomcat to work.

Comment: There is a workaround however. Edit conf/boxfuse.conf file and uncomment property 'ports.http=80'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boxfuse 1.8.6 has an unfortunate regression that slipped through our tests. This has been fixed in 1.8.7. Simply update by issuing

```
boxfuse -u
```

and everything will work as expected.